# VSCode Notebook Buttons Gray

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I open a .ipynb notebook in VSCode, the buttons at the top are grayed out and I can't click them. When I try running a cell, it just doesn't execute it even if it's a simple command and just has the * symbol. I tried reinstalling VSCode but that didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: The top of my VSCode for the notebook: the buttons are gray]

Comment: Will you please go the _View → Output_ menu, and then in the dropdown menu to the top-right of the panel that appears, choose "Jupyter", and then send the output you find via https://pastebin.com/ and share the link?

Comment: Here it is! https://pastebin.com/nPB5Vm8Y Sorry, it's a bit long, wasn't sure how much to add in.

Comment: @radishearrings777 Could you try to reinstall the Python Extension or update it(it is different from mine)? And in fact, I can't see the problems in your screenshot, could you provide a bigger one? thanks.